# When I run my program my if statements never return anything

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x

I was trying to make a simple Ideal Gases calculator but for some reason I cannot seem to get any of my if statements to return any values.

```
def Ideal():
    p = input("Pressure:")
    v = input("Volume:")
    n = input("Moles:")
    t = input("Temperature in K:")
    r = 8.31

    if p is None:
        y =(n*r*t)/v
        return y
    elif v is None:
        return(n*r*t)/p
    elif n is None:
        return (p*v)/(r*t)
    elif n is None:
        return (p*v)/(n*r)
```

I went from the above code to this

```
def input_float(prompt):
result = input(prompt)
if result:
    return float(result)
else:
    return None

def Ideal():
p = input_float("Pressure:")
v = input_float("Volume:")
n = input_float("Moles:")
t = input_float("Temperature in K:")
r = 8.31

if p is None:
    y =(n*r*t)/v
    print(y)
elif v is None:
    u = (n*r*t)/p
    print(u)
elif n is None:
    i = (p*v)/(r*t)
    print(i)
elif t is None:
    o = (p*v)/(n*r)
    print(o)
else:
    print("This should never happen")
```

Ideal()

and now it works great. But I am guessing there was an easier way to go about this and since I am here to learn I would love to here opinions.

Comment: Python is pick about indentation, you may want to look into that.

Comment: `if` statements aren't functions, so they're not designed to "return" anything; I believe what you mean is that your if statements never evaluate as `True`. (The reason for this is explained in icktoofay's answer.)

Comment: Its generally good practice to avoid having an `if`/`elif` chain without putting an `else` at the end, even if one of the `if` conditions should always be true. What you do in the `else` block may depend on the details of your code (raising an exception is sometimes appropriate). At a minimum, do something like `print("This should never happen")` so you can see if something unexpected is going on (as it is, in the current situation).

Comment: You have two tests for the same condition: ```elif n is None:```, you may want to see if that was intentional.

Answer (score 1):

`input` gives you a string. If the user provides no input, you don't get `None` — you get an empty string. You might want to make a new function to take input from the user but return `None` if they enter nothing and parse it otherwise:

```
def input_float(prompt):
    result = input(prompt)
    if result:
        return float(result)
    else:
        return None
```

Then you can replace the `input`s in your program with `input_float`s.

Comment: … or `return float(result) if result else None`.

Comment: If you simply press "enter" past the input prompt, I get an exception rather than no input. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Irwin: I suspect you're using Python 2; the question and my answer relate to Python 3. Python 3's `input` is Python 2's `raw_input`; Python 2's `raw_input` is Python 3's `eval(input(...))`.